# iPhone: Is it possible to gift paid app to another user?

Tags: applications, iphone, ios

Is it possible to gift apps to another iTunes account ?

I want to accomplish the following:

Select payed application → Gift to friend → Payment of app → Send to friend → Friend can download it as a gift (for free)

Is that possible ? And if yes, how can I do that ?

Please provide me some links or detail for this idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible for Apps and music. For obvious reasons, you can only gift Apps that cost money. Unfortunately this is not possible with books from the iBook store.

**From your Mac**

1. Navigate to the App Store in iTunes
2. Find the app you want to gift
3. Click the little down arrow next to the "Buy App" button
4. A menu will appear, and one of the options is "Gift This App"

[image: Gift an app from your mac]

**From your iDevice**

1. Open the App Store app
2. Find the app you want to gift
3. Scroll to underneath the the screenshots
4. Tap the "Gift This App" button

[image: Gift an app from your iDevice]

Comment: Can I implement this in my app? where I can allow users to select any app and then he can gift it to his friend. Is it possible ?

Comment: @iPhone I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but apps can only be gifted through the app store.

Comment: Thanks for interest. Can I gift other app from my app. For example, New app(my app), Now I have list of other paid app like first,second,third and etc. in this "new app" and now can I gift those(first,second,third and etc.) other paid apps to friend using iPhone only?

Comment: @iPhone you can't gift apps from anywhere except the app store. What you could maybe do is figure out what the link is that the "Gift This App" button goes to, and then put *that* in your app, and use a call to `-[UIApplication openURL:]` to start the process. But the gifting itself can only be done through the app store.

Comment: $999.99 app? You must be a really good friend. Can I befriend you? (on the side note can we do this for songs and books as well?)

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo yeah, I thought it'd be amusing to pick an absurdly expensive app for the screenshots. :)  You can gift songs/albums through iTunes, but not from an iOS device.  Books don't appear to be giftable at all.

Comment: @DaveDeLong I can give music from my iOS iPad, iBooks is indeed not possible. Might be this is also different per country. I updated the answer with this info as it is about buying items from the Store.